# Cannot change table name with migration using entity framework code first with existing database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

i have a problem when trying to change table name when doing migration using ef code first with an existing database. In existing database, i got a table name "Cities", and I want to change it to "City". In mapping file, i declare:

```
public CityMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.CityId);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.CityCode)
            .HasMaxLength(64);

        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(128);

        this.Property(t => t.SysNo)
            .HasMaxLength(64);

        this.Property(t => t.No_Ins)
            .HasMaxLength(64);

        this.Property(t => t.CountryCode)
            .HasMaxLength(64);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("City");
        this.Property(t => t.CityId).HasColumnName("CityId");
        this.Property(t => t.CityCode).HasColumnName("CityCode");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        this.Property(t => t.SysNo).HasColumnName("SysNo");
        this.Property(t => t.No_Ins).HasColumnName("No.Ins");
        this.Property(t => t.CountryId).HasColumnName("CountryId");
        this.Property(t => t.CountryCode).HasColumnName("CountryCode");
        this.Property(t => t.Note).HasColumnName("Note");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Country)
            .WithMany(t => t.Cities)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CountryId);

    }
```

After that, i exec migration command "add-migration initial -ignorechanges" and "update-database -verbose", but nothing happens in the existing database. So have i missed something? thank you so much.